# Create a bst for a small regional journal

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bst

I am working on a publication for a small regional journal to which I cannot find a pre-existing natbib bibliography style which meets their guidelines. I am not an expert LaTeX user, in fact I am fumbling my way through it. I tried using the `makebst` command in the terminal, but at a few of the multiple choice questions none of the supplied answers fit what the journal wanted for their format. Should I just get as close as I can with `makebst` and then go in and make the necessary edits? Or is there a better option for someone who is not particularly good with LaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous.

I think the syntax is more simple than bst.

`main.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{Baumann23}
\cite{RungsirisilpCTM23}
\cite{BernalC23}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

`ref.bib`

```
@book{Baumann23,
  author    = {Franziska Baumann},
  title     = {Embodied Human-Computer Interaction in Vocal Music Performance},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year      = {2023}
}
@article{RungsirisilpCTM23,
  author    = {Nuttawat Rungsirisilp and Pakaratee Chaiyawat and Sakaowrat Techataweesub and Aungsunee Meesrisuk and Yodchanan Wongsawat},
  title     = {Applying Action Observation During a Brain-Computer Interface on Upper Limb Recovery in Chronic Stroke Patients},
  journal   = {{IEEE} Access},
  volume    = {11},
  pages     = {4931--4943},
  year      = {2023}
}
@inproceedings{BernalC23,
  author    = {Arturo Miguel Russell Bernal and Jane Cleland{-}Huang},
  title     = {Hierarchically Organized Computer Vision in Support of Multi-Faceted Search for Missing Persons},
  booktitle = {{FG}},
  pages     = {1--7},
  publisher = {{IEEE}},
  year      = {2023}
}
```

`mybst.bst`

```ini
TEMPLATES:
article = <au>. <title>. <journal>, <year>[, <volume>(<issue>):<startpage>--<endpage>|, <volume>:<startpage>--<endpage>|, <startpage>--<endpage>].
book = <au>. <title>. <publisher>, <year>[, <volume>(<issue>):<startpage>--<endpage>|, <volume>:<startpage>--<endpage>|, <startpage>--<endpage>].
inproceedings = <au>. <title>. <booktitle>, <year>[, <volume>:<startpage>--<endpage>|, <startpage>--<endpage>].

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
authorlist = <author.to_namelist()>
authorname.n = [<authorlist.n.first> ]<authorlist.n.last>
au = <authorname.0>, ..., <authorname.N>
```

And download from `bibulous.py` from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nzhagen/bibulous/master/bibulous.py

Put `bibulous.py`, `main.tex`, `mybst.bst`, and `ref.bib` in the same folder.

Run these commands below:

```shell
pdflatex -synctex=-1 main.tex
python bibulous.py main.aux
pdflatex -synctex=-1 main.tex
pdflatex -synctex=-1 main.tex
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response, and I apologize for my delayed response. Unfortunately I was not able to make bibulous work for me, but I did manage to get makebst to work.

Comment: I believe one of the best suggestion

Comment: @MacMcMahan If you satisfy with the suggestion, then please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark